# Getting error while trying to code custom sort function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to make a custom sorted function for integers and floats. In this code, what I did was remove duplicates at first and then tried to use pop function to take out the minimum number from the list and and append it into the empty list so every number would be in the right order. However, when I'm trying to pop the minimum number from "aList" I'm getting this traceback:

```
line 15, in <module>
    sortedList.append(delDupes.pop(delDupes[test]))
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

but if I replace, that line above with sortedList.append(test), then I'm getting this error:

```
line 14, in <module>
    test = delDupes.index(min(delDupes))
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

This what code looks like:

```
aList = [30, 30, 30, 20, 20, 20, 25, 25, 25, 10, 10, 10, 50, 50, 50]

delDupes = []
sortedList = []

for i in aList:
    if i not in delDupes:
        delDupes.append(i)

adLoop = True


while adLoop:
    test = delDupes.index(min(delDupes))
    sortedList.append(delDupes.pop(delDupes[test]))
    if len(sortedList) != delDupes:
        adLoop = True
    else:
        adLoop = False

print(sortedList)
```

I'm using while loop so that once it pops out the minimum number, the loop should start again and pop the next minimum number until length of sortedList becomes same as the original length of delDupes

Comment: What's the error with trace?

Comment: I'm getting pop index out of range

Comment: Do you mean `delDupes.pop(test)`? `delDupes[test]` will return the number at that index, then you're using that number as the index to pop.

Comment: Add the full traceback.

Comment: I tried that at first, but in that case I'm getting "min() arg is an empty sequence" and I can't even think of what it is.

Comment: I'm getting "ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence" in case I use delDupes.pop(test) and "IndexError: pop index out of range" in cases of what I have in the code above

Comment: You should step through this and look at the values of your variables. It seems like you are just guessing. You can't use `delDupes.pop(delDupes[test]))`. You will be trying to pop index `10` which doesn't exist. You need something like `delDupes.pop(test)` since `test` is the index. Then you also need to guard against `delDupes` being empty.  Maybe `while adLoop and delDupes:`?

Comment: I just added "while adLoop and delDupes" and it worked. Could you explain what did that do?

Comment: @dante--all you really need is `while delDupes:`  This causes the loop to terminate when delDupes becomes empty.

Comment: now I understand, thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @dante `sorted(set(aList))` is enough. Btw `set` is the best to remove duplicates.

Comment: I was trying to not use them

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. I would recommend reading the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. As noted by @Carcigenicate, it should be `delDupes.pop(test)` not `delDupes.pop(delDupes[test])`
2. As you pop items from `delDupes` it gets smaller as `sortedList` grows so the condition `len(sortedList) != delDupes` should be `len(delDupes) != 0`

The corrected code (with minimal changes) looks like this:

```
aList = [30, 30, 30, 20, 20, 20, 25, 25, 25, 10, 10, 10, 50, 50, 50]

delDupes = []
sortedList = []

for i in aList:
    if i not in delDupes:
        delDupes.append(i)

adLoop = True


while adLoop:
    test = delDupes.index(min(delDupes))
    sortedList.append(delDupes.pop(test))
    if len(delDupes) != 0:
        adLoop = True
    else:
        adLoop = False

print(sortedList)
```

Comment: That whole code could simply be: `sortedList = sorted(set(aList))`.

Comment: I know, but the question was "Could anyone explain what's wrong here?", not "How do I best solve the problem?"

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because in this line

```
sortedList.append(delDupes.pop(delDupes[test]))
```

`pop` expect element index where you are providing the value of `delDuples` by index `test`

Here the working code:

```
aList = [30, 30, 30, 20, 20, 20, 25, 25, 25, 10, 10, 10, 50, 50, 50]

delDupes = []
sortedList = []

for i in aList:
    if i not in delDupes:
        delDupes.append(i)

adLoop = True


while adLoop:
    if delDupes:
        test = delDupes.index(min(delDupes))
    else:
        break
    try:
        sortedList.append(delDupes.pop(delDupes.index(delDupes[test])))
    except:
        x = 10
    if len(sortedList) != delDupes:
        adLoop = True
    else:
        adLoop = False
```

print(sortedList)

That result in: [10, 20, 25, 30, 50]

UPD: as Ch3steR mentioned in comments, it'll be useful for you to know how this can be done in more efficient and simple way:

```
sorted(set(aList))
```

Comment: `sorted(set(aList))` is enough. `set` is the best way to remove duplicates.

Comment: This is true, but I guess author used this code for learning purpose and he asking to help with his code to get it work.

Comment: I meant to mention this method also. So, he gets to know a more efficient way to do it.